# Passing an image ID to a function.

Tags: javascript, variables

What I thought seemed so simple has me stumped. I want to have a page full of product thumbnail images, which are just the full image reduced to a smaller size in my HTML. Click on it for a full sized image in the temporary pop-up window.

This works, but how can I pass along the image name as a variable so I don't have to re-write the function for each image. For instance, click pic1.jpg and you get the popup with pic1.jpg in it. pic2.jpg calls up pic2.jpg in the popup, etc. etc. infinitely.

Here is my code for the HTML.

```
<p>
    <a href="javascript:productpop()">
        <img src="products/pic1.jpg" id="image" height="100" border=0 />
        <br />
        CLICK FOR POPUP
    </a>.
</p>
```

Here is my popup window code.

```
function productpop() {
    newproduct=window.open('','name','height=500,width=500');
    var tmp = newproduct.document;
    tmp.write('<html><head><title>Product Pop-up</title>');
    tmp.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="productpop.css">');
    tmp.write('</head><body>');
    tmp.write('<p align="center">');
    tmp.write('<img src="products/pic1.jpg"></p>');
    tmp.write('<p align="center"><a href="javascript:self.close()">Close</a> Window.    </p>');
    tmp.write('</body></html>');
    tmp.close();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I want to learn this, not just buy commercial code.

Comment: Now that's a descriptive title...

Comment: Replace `<img src="products/pic1.jpg">` with `'<img src=' + this.src + '>'`?

Comment: don't use popup's ppl prefer in window modals like lightbox

Comment: @Tyblitz this will refer to the a not to the img.

Comment: @edduvs Right.. Lol, I forgot it was on the anchor

Comment: @edduvs `this` refers to neither the anchor nor image because no context has been set, so it will be the `window` object.

Comment: I could've sworn I was thinking about that and wrote about jQuery functions. That's correct indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of var objects and loop through the array when you write to each var.  Change the name of the pic line to this:

```
tmp[i].write("<img src=\"products/pic" + (i + 1) + ".jpg\"></p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a parameter to your function, i.e.:

```
<p><a href="javascript:productpop('products/pic1.jpg')"><img src="products/pic1.jpg" id="image" height="100" border=0 /><br />CLICK FOR POPUP</a>.</p>
```

and then use it in your function as:

```
function productpop(imagePath) {
    newproduct=window.open('','name','height=500,width=500');
    var tmp = newproduct.document;
    tmp.write('<html><head><title>Product Pop-up</title>');
    tmp.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="productpop.css">');
    tmp.write('</head><body>');
    tmp.write('<p align="center">');
    tmp.write('<img src="' + imagePath + '"></p>');
    tmp.write('<p align="center"><a href="javascript:self.close()">Close</a> Window.    </p>');
    tmp.write('</body></html>');
    tmp.close();
}
```

More information about parameters can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id via a parameter in the function like this:

```
<a href="javascript:productpop(1)">
    <img src="products/pic1.jpg" id="image" height="100" border=0 />
</a>.
```

And the javascript function should be defined like this :

```
function productpop(picID) {
    newproduct=window.open('','name','height=500,width=500');
    var tmp = newproduct.document;
    tmp.write('<html><head><title>Product Pop-up</title>');
    tmp.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="productpop.css">');
    tmp.write('</head><body>');
    tmp.write('<p align="center">');
    tmp.write('<img src="products/pic'+picID+'.jpg"></p>');
    tmp.write('<p align="center"><a href="javascript:self.close()">Close</a> Window.    </p>');
    tmp.write('</body></html>');
    tmp.close();
}
```

This way you'll pass the picID which you'll have to manually enter in the  element.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the anchor to `<a onclick="javascript:productpop(event)" href="#">`
Then you will have access to the src attribute in your code (although it will be the whole URL):

```
function productpop(event) { // Added argument
    newproduct=window.open('','name','height=500,width=500');
    var tmp = newproduct.document;
    tmp.write('<html><head><title>Product Pop-up</title>');
    tmp.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="productpop.css">');
    tmp.write('</head><body>');
    tmp.write('<p align="center">');
    tmp.write('<img src="' + event.target.childNodes[1].src + '"></p>'); // Use argument to insert source
    tmp.write('<p align="center"><a href="javascript:self.close()">Close</a> Window.    </p>');
    tmp.write('</body></html>');
    tmp.close();
}
```

So by making it an onclick event you have access to all the events information, including it's target i.e. the element that was clicked on and triggered the event. Then you can retrieve that elements attributes.